# Behavior of ^ in javascript

Tags: javascript

`alert(15^2)` - behaves as `alert(15-2)`, alerts `13`
`alert(15^10)` - behaves as `alert(15-10)`, alerts `5`

So it subtracts second number from the first, if the second number is smaller.
But if the second number is larger, for example

`alert(15^16)`, it sums them, behaves as `alert(15+16)` and alerts `31`.

`alert(15^3^4)` behaves as `alert(15-3-4)`, so it alerts 8.

While

`alert(15^3^2)` behaves as `alert(15-3+2)`, so it alerts 14.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Comment: It's a bitwise XOR, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR

Comment: also for testing purposes, using console.log(15^2) saves you having to hit the enter key/mouse to close the message box :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called XOR. For each bit on each number it outputs a 1 if both are different.

```
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
```

So when you have the operation `15^2` you are doing:

```
1111 XOR
0010
----
1101
```

Which looks like a substraction, but for those special cases only.

As with the cases on multiple times, for example `15^3^4 = (15^3)^4` so you first calculate `15^3` and then the result with 4:

```
1111 XOR (15)
0011     (3)
----
1100     (12)
```

and then:

```
1100 XOR (12)
0100     (4)
----
1000     (8)
```

Therefore, `15^3^4 = 8`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I understood, but could you add explanations on `alert(15^3^4)`, `alert(15^3^2)`.

Comment: @nicael 15^3^4 = (15^3)^4

Answer (score 1):

That is a bitwise XOR operation you are doing, not powers.

According to MDN:

> Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either but not both operands are ones.

In javascript, you can use `Math.pow` to do the math operation.

So

```
alert(Math.pow(15, 2))
```

Shows a messagebox with the value `225`.